# How to close all windows in a WindowGroup?

Tags: macos, swiftui, window, persistence

I am coding in SwiftUI for MacOS and I'm looking for a way to close all open windows.

My app has what Apple calls a [data-driven window group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup#identifying-a-data-driven-window-group): when a user clicks on an on-screen object for more information, a new detail window appears specific to the object they click on.

The problem I'm having is that these windows are persistent by default. When the user quits and runs the app again, all the detail screens that were previously open appear again, even when the items they describe no longer exist. I do not want *any* of these windows to appear upon restart.

Here's the (simplified) code. My `App.swift` looks like this:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup { // main window
            ContentView()
                .environment(vm)
        }
        WindowGroup(for: Item.ID.self) { $itemID in
            ItemDetails(itemID: itemID)
                .environment(vm)
        }
    }
}
```

And my `ContentView.swift`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var vm
    @Environment(\.openWindow) private var openWindow

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(vm.items) { item in
            Button(item.name) {
                openWindow(value: item.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the user can close the windows manually, but if they create 15 new `ItemDetails` windows in a session and then quit. I don't want them to have to start their next session by closing all the "leftover" windows from their previous session.

Alternatively, I could have the app close all its windows upon quit. But I'd like a solution that works even when the app quits unexpectedly. Such as when Xcode halts it to replace it with a new version. :)

Any ideas how I can make the windows created by user button taps *not* persist? Or, that failing, at least close all the windows in a WindowGroup programmatically?

Comment: Could you please provide an working example with your simplified ViewModel? I made an working example. I click the buttons and a new window opens. If I restart the app, only the main window is showed.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77775333/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know now, why on my Mac the windows were closed: In the system settings, I deactivated "restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps". After enabling it, I had the same behaviour.

So you have two options: You can disable this setting with:

```
defaults write [application identifier] NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

or you can use this code:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows")
    }
}

@main
struct StackOverflowTestApp: App {
        
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    ...
}
```

You may need to restart the app a second time to see the effect.

**UPDATE**:

You don't need an `AppDelegate`, you can just use the `init` in the `App`:

```
@main
struct StackOverflowTestApp: App {

    init() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you - This is the kind of solution I'm hoping for! And we're getting so much closer. It works when the app quits intentionally, but not when it crashes or the process is killed. I would really like to be able to prevent windows from reopening in those settings too. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it. I killed the app, I also let it crash by accessing an array out of range, but after restarting the application, the windows didn't open again.

Comment: The situation that I tested is that I'm running the app with Xcode on the Mac, and I issue the Run command (⌘R) again without first quitting the app. Xcode tells me "message from debugger: killed" and it restarts the app with all the windows open again. The only other setting I tested was where I quit the app and relaunch, which works fine: no leftover windows.

Comment: I don't know, what Xcode does in those circumstances, maybe it has to do sth. with the fact, that Xcode "replaces" the first run. It should workd in "normal" cases, but if you want to go sure, I would additionally do what alexo suggested: Save the ids when using `openWindow` to the `UserDefaults` and in the init or `onAppear` of the App you can dismiss them.

Answer (score 1):

"Any ideas how I can make the windows created by user button taps not persist?"

When the user creates a new window, you could potentially check for other existing windows and delete them using dismiss().

Also when launching the app you could have a userDefault and set a flag for when the app is launched, and delete the existing windows

Comment: Unfortunately my question remains - _how_ to "delete the existing windows" as you say. If I had an array of them as objects it would be easy to close them; my issue is that I don't know how to obtain that array upon startup. Are you suggesting I store a reference in UserDefaults every time a window is opened, and look in userDefaults on startup to close all the stored windows? That's an interesting idea, but I don't know how to store a persistent reference like that - do you?

Comment: Yeah that's sorta what I was going for. Maybe every time a new window is opened add that id to an array in UserDefault? Then on startup check that array and wipe it? Now I'm sorta spitballing but that'd be what I'd try.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I can assume that `vm.items` persist in app sessions. If I'm wrong, please provide a complete, minimally reproducible code.

If I'm right, then the problem is logical, not technical. What I mean is that you have to keep two separate arrays of `Item`s. The first one is the one you already have (persisted in app sessions).

The second one should be an `in-memory` array (standard Swift Array), representing the **state** of opened windows.

It's difficult to provide a code example because the provided information is not complete and heavily depends on your `ViewModel`, but I think you will get the idea :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately `vm.items` may be completely different each time the app runs. It wouldn't make any sense to have it persist (at least apart from the windows issue) - Think of it as a list of list of today's to-do items, pulled from a database. The list changes from app execution to app execution, and may refer to objects in the database that will be archived and unavailable the next time the app launches. I'll try to think of a way to give a minimal complete example; it's difficult given the circumstances.